# Using Bash insteal of Perl? (bashrc)

Tags: bash, perl

I was using a bash script in my bashrc and until now everything worked.

Today, i decided to install Perl on my computer (since I'm looking to learn the language) using the method on the website learn.pearl

```
curl -L xrl.us/installperlnix | bash
```

(urls are not accepted )

The problem is that now, my script doesn't work anymore, I'm having the error:
"no such file
export PERLBREW_BASHRC_VERSION=0.78"

I tried to use the command "perlbrew switch-off" but it seems that I don't have the program perlbrew installed, and my bashrc is starting with #!/bin/bash so I'm completely lost on you to fix the problem.

I would appreciate some help.

Thanks !

Comment: Post your bashrc.

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you got everything to download the perlbrew, like curl or wget, it is simple to check, try one of theses:

> which curl
>
> which wget

If you have one of them you are able to download, otherwise you will need to install either curl or wget.

The latest realease of perlbrew is 0.78.

After theses first steps try to download it again as you did.

There is a mini tutorial which you can use as a guide:

https://perlbrew.pl/

Also I am not sure if you have it installed so you could use:

> which perlbrew

To find out if you have it or not. Maybe you forgot the step as describe in the perlbrew site:

> sudo cpan App::perlbrew
>
> perlbrew init

Because it seems like your environment was not set yet.